CrewAI Tools: pydantic models Cannot instantiate typing.union
Was following along with a tutorial for crew ai: https://github.com/bhancockio/nextjs-crewai-basic-tutorial
I'm running this on python 3.11.9.
I'm trying to run the repo however i'm getting an error:

TypeError(f"cannot instantiate {self!r}")
Type Error: Cannot Instantie typing.union

These error seem to come from handing the pydantic models, However I think the error is coming from the library crewai_tools and not my code.
The Models I'm using do not using union:
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel


class NamedUrl(BaseModel):
    name: str
    url: str


class PositionInfo(BaseModel):
    company: str
    position: str
    name: str
    blog_articles_urls: List[str]
    youtube_interviews_urls: List[NamedUrl]


class PositionInfoList(BaseModel):
    positions: List[PositionInfo]

looks like the error is occuring in:
`class FixedDOCXSearchTool` 

That tool existing in the CrewAI-Tools Library however I'm not importing it into my code anywhere
How can I fix the pydantic models, inside the tools or force this to run?
